# how to consult file as a module in jpl

Tags: java, prolog, swi-prolog, jpl

I am trying to consult Prolog file as a module, since jpl does not support multiple prolog vms.

In swipl console, I can do something like this successfully

```
?- consult(mod1:'data/load.pro') .
```

In java (well, it is actually scala, but they are all on top of jvm), I can consult file directly w/o issue

```
scala> import jpl._

scala> val q = new Query("consult", Array[Term](new Atom("data/load.pl")))

scala> q.query()
...
true
```

however, when I tried to consult the file as module, I always get the exception.

```
scala> val q = new Query("consult", Array[Term](new Atom("mod1:data/load.pl")))

scala> q.query()
  jpl.PrologExcepion:  PrologException: error(existence_error(source_sink, 'mod1:data/load.pl'), _0)
    at jpl.Query.get1(Query.java:336)
    at jpl.Query.hasMoreSolutions(Query.java:258)
    at jpl.Query.oneSolution(Query.java:688)
    at jpl.Query.query(Query.java:747)
    at .<init>(<console>:15)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    ....
```

Anybody can point me to the correct way of consulting prolog file as module in jpl? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can swap the module qualification on predicate, and of course that would allow you to pass in the *full path* of your source file:

```
val q = new Query("mod1:consult('full_path_to/load.pl')")
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work, I got exception, "jpl.JPLException: Term.putParams: more actual params than formal". What only works so far is I put the prolog syntax directly as a string argument for Query, i.e., new Query("consult(mod1:'data/load.pro')")